# Kendo Grid Inline Editing Date Format Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have been researching this for days without much luck.  I've gone down multiple paths but can't seem to find a solution that works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a Kendo MVC Grid wired up for CRUD

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Games.Models.Game>()    
.Name("Grid")    
.Columns(columns => {        
    columns.Bound(p => p.GameName).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Publisher).Width(75);
    columns.Bound(p => p.MaxPlayers).Width(75);
    columns.Bound(p => p.DateAdded).Width(100).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
```

When I try and edit the DateAdded field, it changes the date from my nicely formatted date of 05/01/2003 to Thu May 1 17:00:00 CDT 2003 and throws an error when you try to update the data (any data I enter is converted to the Day, Month, Time, TimeZone year format).

The grid throws a "The field DateAdded must be a date error".

I've tried using an Editor Template using the Kendo Date Picker, but the data is not updating into my model.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.DateAdded).Width(100).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("DateTime");
```

Editor Template:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                .Name("datepicker")
                .Format("M/d/yyyy")
)
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?  I can skip using the date picker if I can update the date inline, but I can't get either method to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime is validated against the **culture** specified on the client (the kendo culture). Keep in mind that validation and format of the editor are two different things. You should change the culture to one which Date/Month order is the one you use as format. Similar case [here](http://gerardbeckerleg.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/kendo-ui-mvc-grid-datepicker-in-line-and-in-cell-edit-validation-error-the-value-is-not-valid/).

More information about the kendo culture and how to change it can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/definecultureinfo).

Comment: This was a really great response, sorry for the long delay to answer.  I ended up going with Kendo MVC and it all worked great.  I think your answer is solid.